# Network Connection Status Change

Tags: android

I would like to develop an app, that can works offline but I also want sending this offline values to server when device comes online. I used broadcast receiver to trigger service(when internet connection arrives) but it is not supported anymore, what is/are the alternatives for this situation ?

Comment: Use a `JobShedular` to sync to server .

Comment: Syncadapter ContentProvider used together. Maybe this tool will help as well https://github.com/BoD/android-contentprovider-generator

Comment: @ADM i have tried Firebase-Job-Dispatcher but the period time does not consistent.  dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyService.class)
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setTag(Job_tag)// uniquely identifies the job
                .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(5,15))
                .setReplaceCurrent(false)
                .build();

Answer (score 0):

**Try this approach**

> 1. Register receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcast.DataSync"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

> 2. In your `DataSync`

In `onReceive` method check for internet connection,

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()){
    //do your method call for send data to server
}



private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Dont forget to add in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I think this approach does not supported any more, from API 24. [link](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) .

Comment: As this approach is, whenever user is present, broadcast fires

Comment: Ok, i will try it now, I will share result here.

Comment: I tried it on API 26 device, the receiver class does not called. I added permission and receiver in Manifest.

Comment: Try this approach -> add code, run the app. Lock your device and unlock again ...

Comment: Yes, this works, but what if connection arrives when device unlocked, if user does not lock the screen receiver never called ?

Comment: Receiver call whenever user unlock the device

Comment: Ok, I got it but let imagine a scenario, user use app in ofline mode and after that he connect his phone to internet, but he never lock his phone, so according to your solution it never sync data to server since phone never unlocked. But I want to sync data whenever connection arrives.

Comment: I understood your scenario but this will be the worse case I think.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I think we should be ready for worst cases. Thank you for your replies, is there any other way that suited to my concerns.